# Twitter Verification

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Help Rick Astley become verified.

Account Info:
Username: `Rick Astley`
Password: `Twitter Verification`
Security Question:

```
Question: Most hated song?
Answer: Never Gonna Give You Up
```

Twitter sent you this puzzle to solve.
[image]

Hint 1:

> The URL is not the only thing in the picture...

Hint 2:

> The last step of this puzzle is to decode "IZM GWC I ZWJWB" but I'm not sure on how I went from  "OQJ TZN T ZGYVX" or "TZN OQJ T ZGYVX" to "IZM GWC I ZWJWB" since its been over an year since i created this puzzle

Comment: If you're willing to answer this, rot13(Ner gur cynprzragf bs gur yrggre frdhraprf va gur oyhr cneg vzcbegnag?)

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 rot13(Abg ernyyl)

Comment: Haven't been able to get any further with what I've found so far, maybe a hint could help?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I added a hint

Comment: @VarunW. Can you perform a full rewrite of this puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (?)

---

**Step 1**

> The inside of the tick contains some text, which says '[https://pastebin.com/m9BY038X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)'

**Step 2**

> The website link takes us to a locked paste, with requires a password. Now what could this password be... 'Never Gonna Let You Down', 'Rickroll', 'Twitter Verification'... nope? Well the security question is about the song, so how about '**dQw4w9WgXcQ**' - the youtube code for the viral hit...

**Step 3**

> Entering this password unlocks the paste, to give us a very cryptic message:
>
> '**Luck is not the only key**'

This is as far as I've got, not sure what the text means

Comment: Rot13(Gur uvqqra fgevatf ner T, OQJ, TZN naq ZGYVX? .)

Comment: @Jarvis rot13(Lbh ner irel pybfr. Gur gevpx vf gb nanylmr gur grkg "yhpx vf abg gur bayl xrl" va n tenzzngvpny jnl gb svaq n ahzore naq penpx vg hfvat gur grkg Wneivf sbhaq)

Comment: @VarunW. When I see luck... I SEE 13!!!

Comment: @1357924680a What do you mean can you elaborate?

Comment: @VarunW. 13 IS UNLUCKY!

Comment: @1357924680a I dont remember how to solve this puzzle but I remember the answer.